# Swashbuckle Swagger: How to show type of array of models parameter?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am using latest 2.4 version of https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to generate documentation for  AspNetCore Controller method having 2 parameters: guid and list of models.

```
[HttpPost("MyMethod/{ReferenceId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod(Guid referenceId, List<ApiProfile> passengers)
```

The first parameter generates correctly, but the second doesn't understand type and shows just array(no type)

```
Passengers
array
(query)
```

And in json:

```
"parameters": [
    {
        "name": "passengers",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "",
        "required": false,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {},
        "collectionFormat": "multi"
    },
```

Note that the type ApiProfile is shown at the bottom under Models section:

```
ApiProfile {
    description:    API Object
    Id  string($uuid)
    Email   string
    salutation  string
    firstName   string
    lastName    string
    dateOfBirth string($date-time)
}
```

And in json:

```
"definitions": {
    "ApiProfile": {
        "description": "API Object",
        "type": "object",    
        "properties": {"Id": {"format": "uuid","type": "string"},
        "Email": {"type": "string"},
        "salutation": {"type": "string"},
        "firstName": {"type": "string"}
...
```

I need an advice how to describe type of  List of request parameters to be shown in Swagger UI.

I've tried to assign [SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(PeopleRequest), typeof(ListPeopleRequestExample))] but not sure how to do it with 2 parameters.
Also I tried to temporary exclude first parameter, but have the same behaviour.

Update: I've created a minimal version, but have the same behaviour.

```
  [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SwashbuckleTest : Controller
    {
         [HttpPost]
        [Route("{id}")]
        public SwashbuckleTestProfile Post(Guid id, List<SwashbuckleTestProfile> companies)
        {
            return companies.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    public class SwashbuckleTestProfile
    {

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Full example can be loaded from https://github.com/MNF/Samples/tree/master/SwashbuckleExample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have to do anything special or describe anything. 
Swashbuckle should take care of that...
*Smells like a bug*

I tested something similar with my project Swagger-Net and it renders ok:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=MultiParam#/MultiParamPost/MultiParamPost_Post

```C
    [Route("{id}")]
    public Company Post(Guid id, List<Company> companies)
    {
        return companies.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Here is the relevant JSON that code outputs:

```JS
      {
        "name": "companies",
        "in": "body",
        "required": true,
        "schema": {
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Company"
          },
          "xml": {
            "name": "Company",
            "wrapped": true
          },
          "type": "array"
        }
      }
```

I guess if you really want to get Swashbuckle you can use an IDocumentFilter and change the schema to look more like mine.

**Update:** After the playing with provided minimal version, it seems that adding `[FromBody]` makes a big change to the schema in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

```C
    [Route("{id}")]
    public Company Post(Guid id, [FromBody]List<Company> companies)
```

Comment: Which version of SwashBuckle are you using? I've created a minimal version(see question update), but have no luck.

Comment: I'm using my own project Swagger-Net: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net _ but I still have not created a net core version

Comment: Thanks. If it is a bug in SwashBuckle, I would report to them

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim see my update... try adding [FromBody]

Comment: Thanks, it helps. I've also reported it as a bug https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/684